# База адресов под веб php+mysql КЛАДР

Tags: php, mysql

Ищется база адресов, классификатор КЛАДР. Подскажите, где можно взять-скачать для использования? На сайте налогов есть только в дбф, что мне не подходит.

Comment: уже и КЛАДР заменили...

Answer (score 3):

КЛАДР устарела, сейчас есть [ФИАС](http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/DownloadPage.aspx). Помимо DBF, база предоставляется в формате XML. Можно потратить время на конвертацию.

Однако если вам нужен классификатор с точностью до населённых пунктов (без улиц и домов), то рекомендую воспользоваться [этой](http://se-lab.ru/2011/09/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80/) денормализованной базой. Не забудьте грамотно проставить индексы. В своё время для подсказок в адресных полях выбрал именно её — всё искалось быстро.